# covering convex sets by round balls

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $X=\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subset E^n$ be a finite subset in the Euclidean $n$-space, $r>0$ and $B(x_i,r)$ are open balls of radius $r$ centered at the points $x_i\in X, i=1,...,k$. Suppose that
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^k B(x_i,r)\ne \emptyset. 
$$
Is it true that the convex hull of $X$ is contained in
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^k B(x_i,r)   ?
$$
I needed a version of this in some Riemannian geometry argument and while I found a way around, the proof would have been a bit cleaner if this statement were true.

Comment: By Caratheodory's theorem it is enough to consider only  the case when $X$ has $n+1$ points.

Comment: @PaataIvanisvili just a note: since dimension $n$ is arbitrary, this does not look very helpful, we may always assume that $|X|\leqslant n+1$ simply by embedding $E^n\subset E^{|X|-1}$. This is why we could expect a dimension-free proof, like that given below, a priori.

Comment: Thanks. It was only helpful to verify the statement in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. But in general I agree with you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Any point $y$ in the convex hull of $x$'s is a barycenter of some non-negative masses $m_i$ in $x_i$, $\sum m_i=1$, $y=\sum m_i x_i$. Point $y$ minimizes the moment of inertia $I(p)=\sum m_i |p-x_i|^2$, $p\in E^n$, just because $I(p)=I(y)+|p-y|^2$. In particular, it can not happen that all distances $|y-x_i|$ are at least $r$, but for some other point $p$ all distances $|p-x_i|$ are less than $r$.